# hide iPad keyboard

Tags: jquery, ipad, uiwebview

I have UIWebview instance which has a form that the user will fill-in. I need him to fill-in it with hex values.

so I made a custom keyboard layout following jQuery on screen keyboard library found here
http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/

and modified it to work on tablets.

The problem now is that the iPad keyboard still pops up but I managed to ignore the keys when pressed. any better idea to fully hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it

Using jQuery blur elements on touchdown event.

You need to add this code to the document ready function:

```
$('input[type="text"]').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issues. Do you have a repo or jsfiddle of your working version? What changes did you make to jquery.keyboard?

Comment: Check the edits and make sure the $() takes the right controls you are targeting. for me I was targeting all input of type text.